# How to use Scrapy to crawl Data which needs to be parsed before?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to use scrapy spider to get data about Dota 2 from [opendota.com](http://opendota.com).

I would like to start for example at `matchID = 3610252548`, crawl all the data(`matchid`, `duration`, `region`, `totalkills` Radiant and `totalkillsDire`) i need and then increase the `matchID +1` and crawl and so on.

Problems:

1. The data needs to be requested over a `MatchID` (https://www.opendota.com/request) so it takes a few seconds (ca. 15-20) till the data is available.
2. I would like to restrict the amount of match requests to 3/min to keep the load small on the Server.

   ```
   import scrapy

   class OpendotaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   # name der Spinne
   name = "opendota"
   start_urls = ['https://www.opendota.com/matches/3607703223']


   def parse(self, response):
   for post in response.css('body'):

   yield {

       # [0].extract() = extract_first()
       'Winner': post.css('.matchinfo span ::text').extract_first(),
       'Matchid': post.css('.additionalInfo li ::text').extract_first(),
       'Duration': post.css('.duration span ::text').extract()
   }
   ```

   This is the little bit of Code i have until now. Thanks for your help!